# TMUX window names disappear after one command

Tags: tmux

I'm running TMUX on OSX Yosemite. I can name the windows without any issues, but when ever I make a new command (anything, even just enter) it switches back to the "directory" as the window name. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Note: I'm using [TMUXLine](https://github.com/edkolev/tmuxline.vim) if that affects anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option to your Tmux config file:

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```